# Edge and Chrome not respecting ::after absolute position

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-position, pseudo-element

While coding, I stumbled upon some trouble regarding tr::after pseudo-element.
Following example works fine and as expected in FF, and not working properly on Edge, Chrome and Chromium. Tested on Windows and Linux.

`Chrome: Version 79.0.3945.130 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

`Firefox: 71.0 (64-bit)`

Expected: ::after respects originating element relative position, and starts absolute values from it.

What happends in Chrome/Chromium and Edge: ::after starts positioning from body(or html).

Btw, snippet also renders output as expected.
Example source:

```html
<html>

    <style>
        td{
            border: 2px solid red;
        }
        tr{
            position: relative;
        }
        tr::after{
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            border: 4px solid blue;
        }
        </style>

<table>
<tbody>

<tr>
    <td>1_test</td>
    <td>2_test</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1_test</td>
    <td>2_test</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>

</html>
```

Firefox:

[image: FF example]

Chrome:

[image: Chrome example]

Directly from W3C:

> 4.1. Generated Content Pseudo-elements: ::before and ::after
>
> When their computed content value is not none, these pseudo-elements generate boxes as if they were immediate children of their originating element, and can be styled exactly like any normal document-sourced element in the document tree.

[W3C source](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-pseudo-4/#generated-content)

What gives? Am I missing something?

Comment: this a known behavior, need to find the related question